# RESTful Web Service in JSON format

Tags: java, json, rest

I'm new in Restful. i need to create a simple restful that adding 2 inputs in JSON format and return the result also in JSON that i can test it in Postman. if introduce any tutorial or article would be great.

Regards
Babak

Comment: Here you go : https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Comment: take a look at this. If it takes you longer than 10 minutes to set up a functioning Spring-Boot rest service, you're doing something wrong: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Comment: @Stultuske 3 seconds.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also find a simple spring boot restful web service project under below github link

[github Spring boot Employee Service](https://github.com/naveenkulkarni029/spring-boot-employee-service.git)